# Workbook_BeforeClose - Standard saving form pops out but error 91 when clicking on "Cancel"

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a code which, before closing the Workbook, sets all the sheets except one cover as very hidden.
I click on the "X" to close the Workbook, the Macro is fired and everything fine.
Then I receive the classic saving form of Excel and, if I click cancel, I receive error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set.

Could someone explain me why is happening? I used the same code in the past and I did not have this issue

It is interesting because, if there is another excel workbook open at the same time, it works everything fine.

In Tab ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Call my_macro 'defined in a separate module


    Application.EnableEvents = False

End Sub
```

For the sake of clarity in Module 1 the code is following:

```
Public Sub my_macro()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error GoTo skip

Dim ws As Worksheet

Sheet8.Visible = True


For Each ws In Worksheets

    If ws.Name = "Cover" Then

    Else

        ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    End If

Next ws

Sheet8.Select

Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
Application.EnableEvents = True

skip:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line raises the error? You may need to include the code for `my_macro`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see it because I have no option to perform the debug (the button is not active).

Comment: Place the cursor on `Call my_macro`, press F9; a red circle ("breakpoint") should appear in the margin. Now try closing the workbook - excecution will stop at the breakpoint. Press F8 to step through the code line by line.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu for your reply. I did as you suggested and the codes goes smoothly until the end with no problem. After the code the save form appears, and if I click Cancel, and only Cancel, I have the problem. I do not know if after cancel it is missing a pointer to the workbook, I do not know unfortunately

Comment: What about `.DisplayAlerts = False`? Use `ThisWorkbook.Save` before you execute it though.

Comment: Hello Dean. Thank you very much for your answer. If I understand it correctly, this would save the excel automatically on closing, without prompting the saving window, which is causing the problem on the first place. Nevertheless, the user might have for instance accidentally hit the closing button and would like simply to abort the operation, without necessary having to save the file. Did I understand it correctly?